# How to call string in singly linked list in C

Tags: c, string, linked-list, char

Here is my struct

```
struct Student
{
    int numberofstudents;
    float mid,prj,final,hmw;
    int lettergrade;
    int studentnumber;
    char name[40];
    char lastname[40];
    int birthyear;
    float totalgrade;
    struct Student *next;
    
}* head;
```

And I have a function like this

```
void searchbylastname(char *lastname)
{
    struct Student * temp = head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {   
        if(temp->lastname == lastname){
        
            printf("Student Number: %d\n", temp->studentnumber);
            printf("Name: %s\n", temp->name);
            printf("Surname: %s\n", temp->lastname);
            printf("Birth Year: %d\n", temp->birthyear);
            printf("Total Grade: %0.2f\n", temp->totalgrade); 
            return;     
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("Student with student number %s is not found !!!\n", lastname);
}
```

I'm calling it in main with switch case

```
    head = NULL;
    int choice;
    char name[50];
    char lastname[50];
    int birthyear;
    int studentnumber;
    float totalgrade;
    float prj,hmw,mid,final;

    case 6:
                printf("Enter student lastname to search: "); 
                scanf("%s", &lastname);
                searchbylastname(lastname);
                break;
```

but it cannot search by last name, it's automatically direct me here;

```
printf("Student with student number %s is not found !!!\n", lastname);
```

I don't know what to do, if anyone has an opinion, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly compare strings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c)

Comment: Also, you need to `return` from the function when a match is found. Otherwise it will always print he `not found` message.

Comment: It solved by using strcmp function and adding return. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the reason for **not** using a `for()` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`==` does not compare strings in C only the references (addresses) of those strings. If they do not reference the same object they always will be different.

To compare strings you need to use `strcmp` function.

https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strncmp.3.html

You have more problems in your code. Even if you use `strcmp` it will display the message that the student has not been found. If you may have more students having the same surmane (which rather expected you need add a flag)

```
void searchbylastname(char *lastname)
{
    struct Student * temp = head;
    int studentsFound = 0;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {   
        if(!strcmp(temp->lastname,lastname)){
            stutentsFound = 1;
            printf("Student Number: %d\n", temp->studentnumber);
            printf("Name: %s\n", temp->name);
            printf("Surname: %s\n", temp->lastname);
            printf("Birth Year: %d\n", temp->birthyear);
            printf("Total Grade: %0.2f\n", temp->totalgrade);  
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    if(!studentsFound) 
       printf("Students having %s surname have not been found !!!\n", lastname);
}
```

Comment: It solved by using strcmp function and adding return. Thanks a lot.